# What is the software to move screen/laptop to apple TV screen

Tags: appletv

I have seen users that drag their screen to AppleTV on WiFi for presentations and such. I want to be able to do this but can't find the software. I ask and they say it is built in.

I have MacBook Pro with OS X 10.7.5 I have the most recent updates. Is this software available?

Comment: You'll need to upgrade your OS X. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called AirPlay Mirroring.
How to use it on a second generation Apple TV or higher can be found on Apple's site [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5209?viewlocale=en_US) and [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5404)

Comment: And the OP will need OS X 10.8 or later on his Mac. The older 10.7.x he has won't support AirPlay Mirroring.

Comment: OK, I had to upgrade to 10.8 and I now have access to AppleTV/Play mirroring.